# Cases for a one- two- or three-dimensional structure of the Bose-Einstein condensate

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

The phase transition from a classical atomic gas to a Bose-Einstein condensate takes place when a critical phase space density is reached, i.e. when the density of the particles with almost the same momentum is large enough. Can the condensation take place as atomic or molecular chains (one-dimensional) or as surfaces (two-dimensional)?

Please indicate whether your answer is based on theoretical considerations or on observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the assumptions.
E.g. a standard textbook result is that a (non-interacting) BEC is not possible in a one-dimensional harmonic potential. However, this is no longer true if you allow "power law traps", see [Bagnato & Kleppner](http://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.44.7439). In addition, [Ketterle & van Druten](http://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.54.656) showed that the transition temperature in 3D is lowered, if we consider a sample of a *finite size* instead of the thermodynamic limit. It was also proven, that lowering the dimension increases the transition temperature and is therefore favorable for BEC. Hence, you should really be careful on what assumptions you like operate.

Comment: Semoi, what I think is that an external magnetic field will be helpful for condensation at higher temperatures.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Why should it be helpful? Most people use magnetic traps only at "high" temperatures, but not for condensation.

Comment: My next [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600052/does-an-external-magnetic-field-help-to-obtain-a-bec-at-higher-temperatures-than) explains my comment